# Lua: functions and user input?

Tags: lua

I am trying to do a simple program in lua that aims to return a string with certain values based on the user input, however I am having issues scripting this.

For example, if I compile

```
person1 = {
name = "bob" ,
age = 70 ,
hair = "black" ,
};
person2 = {
name = "dan",
age = 40 ,
hair = "blonde" , 
};
describe = function(parent)
print ( "hello " .. parent.name .. " your are " .. parent.age .. " years old
and your hair color is " .. parent.hair )
end
print ("who are you") ;
answer = io.read ();
describe (answer)
```

I would expect that if I wrote `person1` as the input the script would return a string that reads:

> hello bob you are 70 years old and your hair color is black

However it instead returns an error.

The question is, what can I do to fix this? What is the right way to use user input in Lua?

Comment: You should indent your code, it makes it easier to read for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to pass the `object` to the function, not the name. Or search for the object in the global scope:

```
person1 = {
    name = "bob" ,
    age = 70 ,
    hair = "black" ,
};
person2 = {
    name = "dan",
    age = 40 ,
    hair = "blonde" , 
};
describe = function(parent)
    parent = _G[parent]
    print ( "hello " .. parent.name .. " your are " .. parent.age .. " years old and your hair color is " .. parent.hair )
end
print ("who are you") ;
answer = io.read ();
describe (answer)
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/UJxnpx

Comment: sorry, but, what does _G do?

Comment: It is the global scope, where all the global variables are stored. Check the manual for [basic functions](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.1).

Comment: Forget about `_G[parent]` crap. Use something like this: `local data={bob={age=70,hair="black"},dan={age=40,hair="blonde"};` `parent = data[parent] or {age=-1,hair=-1}`. Access to global variables based on user input - its vulnerability.

Comment: Yes, this is more clean solution.